# A-frame link to url with logo

Tags: aframe

I want to use a logo to link to an external URL (regular website, not VR) from inside the scene. This is what I have:

```
<a-entity link="highlighted: true; highlightedColor:#000000; portal:#ec1e1e; href: https://schatzkin.com; title: Back to website; image: assets/logo-lockup-black.png"></a-entity>
```

When I inspect the element, I see the image listed correctly under Link, and also as pano under Material. But in the actual portal, all I see is a solid magenta color.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you sure the path to the image is correct ? it seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/sj7uoLed/7/. Also where did you get the `portal` attribute ?

Comment: I got the portal from an online example I saw. 
I tried running the same code you have in your fiddle on my site and it still didn't display an image in the center. I saw that I wasn't using the latest version of A-frame, but updating didn't help.  
Also, is there a way to create a link that is just text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Using the link component. Provided the image is accessible 
a) the path is correct 
b) there are no CORS issues

setting the `image` attribute should provide background for the `portal` which is part of the `link` component.

```
link="highlighted: true; highlightedColor:#000000; href: https://schatzkin.com;
      titleColor: black; title: Back to website;image: https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpg"
```

---

**2)** Making your own link. Any element can become a link with some js.
You could create your own element, which will change the `window.location` on click:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("mylink", {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
       window.location = this.data.href;
    })
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<a-text color="black" position="1 1 -2" value="goToSchatzkin" 
        mylink="href: https://schatzkin.com;"></a-text>
```

---

Check out both methods in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj7uoLed/19/), or down below:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("mylink", {
    init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        window.location = this.data.href;
      })
    }
  })
</script>

<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
  <a-text color="black" position="1 1.6 -2" value="Click the text"
          mylink="href: https://schatzkin.com;"></a-text>
  <a-entity position="-1 1.6 -2" 
            link="highlighted: true; 
                  highlightedColor:#000000; backgroundColor: red; 
                  href: https://schatzkin.com; titleColor: black; 
                  title: click the image below.;
                  image: https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpg;
                  visualAspectEnabled: true"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Great, just what I wanted to know. Thanks again!

Comment: And dont forget to use a thing to trigger the click (like the cursor component used in the fiddle of the answer)

Comment: @Synn I've added a snipped updated to 1.2.0